# Python is using a lot of RAM during plt.annotate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to add an arrow to the maximum peak in my graph. Because the program makes a lot of graphs with different positions of the maximum, I let the program calculate the arrow with numpy's `argmax()`. I plotted the arrow with the following code:

```
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((20,4), (8,0), sharex=ax1, rowspan=4, colspan=4, axisbg=color)     
ax3.plot(Data2x,Data4y,color2,label=Label4, linewidth=1.5)
ax3.set_ylim([20, 80])  
plt.grid() 
plt.xticks(rotation=0, fontsize=fontsize) 
plt.yticks(rotation=0, fontsize=fontsize)
ax3.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize= 'xx-small')

MaximumStrong = np.argmax(Data4y)
X_Axis = Data2x[MaximumStrong]
Y_Axis = Data4y[MaximumStrong]


ax3.annotate('Maximum', (X_Axis,Y_Axis),
             xytext=(Data2x[MaximumStrong+40], 70), textcoords='data',
             arrowprops={'facecolor':'k', 'arrowstyle':'->','relpos':(0.1, 0.8)},
             fontsize=6, color = 'k',
             horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='bottom')

Begin = pd.Timestamp("".join((dict['NumpySaveFilename'][-14:-4], ' 16:00')))
End = Begin + pd.Timedelta('14 hours')
ax3.set_xlim(Begin, End)
```

The variables `X_Axis` and `X_Axis2` are `pd.to_datetime` and `Y_Axis` is integer. I already found that the bottleneck is in the `X_Axis`. The problem is that Python sucks up all my memory. Can anyone help?

Comment: How much data do you have?

Comment: 14 hours every minute a stamp for each graph